# WordPress Migration - Trouble with Import of MySQL Dump

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, migrate

I'm currently moving sites from one server to another.  In doing this, I'm setting up new dev environment to help test any issues we may have in moving the site.

I've already moved one site, quashing all issues.  I've had some issues with the latest two sites.

My work flow normally is:
1) Export
2) Edit to dev URL in Sublime Text via find/replace
3) Import to DB

Importing a MySQL dump first gave me an error such as
"ERROR at line XXX: unknown command YYY"
In one such scenario, this seems to be caused by an encoding issue (STX) for some unknown character.

I can get such errors to go away by using MySQL flags such as:
-default-character-set=latin1 for the mysqldump and NOT using --default-character-set=utf8 with the import.

This gets me further in the process, as things seem to be working, except no images show in Media (just default.png) for the thumbs.  I've verified that the files exist on the server and checked permissions.  When clicking on an image in Media, I can copy/paste the URL and the image shows properly in a browser.

Another example of where the data isn't fully transferring is that the template used for a page isn't being retained.

I'm at a loss at this point on how to properly export/format/import the MySQL dump.  I've even tried the WordPress repair database utility without any change in results.

Comment: There are WordPress plugins to handle site migration. One good one is Duplicator at https://wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/  It handles many of the niggling details of migration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O. Jones comment mentions a plugin called Duplicator.  I didn't utilize this given our situation so I cannot speak to whether or not it would.  If that would work correctly, I would imagine that the ideal solution for most.

The solution that I've utilized is simple but may not work for those without access to or unfamiliar with MySQL.

The steps are:

1. Export via "mysqldump -u {user} -p {databaseName} >
   {filename.sql}
2. Import like usual (without issues)
3. Log into the new MySQL database where the import was completed, use that database and run the following queries:

   UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = replace(option_value, '{oldURL}', '{newURL}');

   UPDATE wp_posts SET guid = replace(guid, '{oldURL}', '{newURL}');

   UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = replace(post_content, '{oldURL}', '{newURL}');

   UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = replace(meta_value, '{oldURL}', '{newURL}');

These four queries may need to be run for each variation of "http://oldwebsite.com", "http://www.oldwebsite.com", "https://oldwebsite.com", and "https://www.oldwebsite.com".